# Why when I click in a swatch color still show the old color thumbnail?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I created a configurable product with two colors (black and brow)

When I go to product details page and select the brow color still shows the black color product in the thumbnail.

I can't understand this process. I just need to show the color I clicked, so the brow color, not two colors at the same time.

[image]

Need Help! Thank's.

Comment: Please check console for any JS confliction or error.

Comment: There's no conflict in the js console @AbhishekPanchal